The right was missing. (the???) Left intact
Why is there no article before 'left' in this passage about a one-armed monkey?
-- Which arm was it?
-- The right was missing. Left intact.
(from 'Would I lie to You?')

What is "Would I Lie to You?"?  Please give a full citation or more information.

It's a British panel show.  Comedians have to make up (off the cuff) stories about a situation.  On a panel of three, two are fictional, one is factual and the other team has to guess which is the true story.

Obvious words arè often omitted in a terse conversational style. It's called ellipsis, and is normal and very common, especially in informal conversation.
A famous example in literature is Alfred Jingle in Charles Dickens' 'Pickwick Papers':

Rachel Wardle : Ah! Mr. Jingle, if you're trying to insult me.
Mr. Jingle : On the contrary... overheard fat boy... come to warn
you... dreadful danger... tender my services... prevent hub-bub...
other hand... think it an insult... leave room.


Is it done for a dramatic effect?

@Wittyhaire - sometimes, but most often it's just a normal way of talking in an informal conversation.
